# Get total of Select values in HTML to use with session in Python

Tags: python, html, session, select

I'm working on a practice assignment for my bootcamp, and I'm mostly finished with it, but can't quite figure out how to get a total value for Select values from HTML, then display them using session['count'] to put it in a print statement.

```html
        <section class="jumbotron text-center">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Thank you for your order!</h1>
            <p class="lead text-muted">Charging {{session['first_name']}} for {{session['count']}} fruits.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
```

```
@app.route('/checkout', methods=['POST'])         
def checkout():
    print(request.form)
    session['first_name'] = request.form['first_name']
    session['last_name'] = request.form['last_name']
    session['student_id'] = request.form['student_id']
    session['strawberry'] = request.form['strawberry']
    session['raspberry'] = request.form['raspberry']
    session['apple'] = request.form['apple']
    print(f"Charging {request.form['first_name']} for {{session['count'] fruits")
    return render_template("checkout.html")
```

I want the 'count' to be the sum of the selected values from 'strawberry', 'raspberry', & 'apple'. I tried something like session['count'] = request.form['strawberry', 'raspberry', 'apple'], but since it's a dictionary, it threw back an error on my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly you need to retrieve values from your form under fields `strawberry`, `raspberry` and `apple` and them summarize values.
To do so you get value from each field and you cannot do that with

```
request.form['strawberry', 'raspberry', 'apple']
```

You need to access value for each key, so for ex.:

```
session['count'] = request.form['strawberry'] + request.form['raspberry'] + request.form['apple']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this almost solved it, but instead of summing the values, it added them together. So in `<p class="lead text-muted">Charging {{session['first_name']}} for {{session['count']}} fruits.</p>` it came back as "Charging [first_name] for 123 fruits", if the inputs were 1, 2, 3.

Comment: From your original comment though I was able to get it done though, just needed to convert the request.form portions into integers. 
`    session['count'] = int(request.form['strawberry']) + int(request.form['raspberry']) + int(request.form['apple'])` gave me the end result that I was looking for. 

Cheers dude, thanks for your help!